# Why isn't the QIcon function working? (PyQt4)

Tags: python, qt, error-handling, pyqt

```
openFile = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('Black.png'), 'Open', self)
```

When I run the module after adding the action, when I click on file, the action open does not have an icon.

Comment: Does `Black.png` exist in the location you are running your script from?

Comment: Its just an image stored in the pictures folder of my computer named Black.

Comment: That wasn't my question. Let me rephrase: Did you provide the correct path to your image?

Comment: Oh. No I don't think so.

Comment: @user122083 Why do you expect that `QIcon` will read your mind as to location of the icon file?

Comment: Because I was following a tutorial called http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/menusandtoolbars/ and that's the way they showed the code for importing an icon.

Comment: @user122083 Following a tutorial doesn't dispense you from understanding what you're doing :)

Comment: I didn't know how it worked I was learning and making mistakes.

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide the full path to your image:

```
openFile = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon(r'C:\Development\icons\Black.png'), 'Open', self)
```

In this example, I'm providing the absolute path to the image. I also passed it as a raw string, so that I don't have to escape all those slashes.

You can also provide a relative path to your image:

```
openFile = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon(r'icons\Black.png'), 'Open', self)
```

This way assumes that your application layout looks like this:

```
Development\
    icons\
        Black.png
    script.py
```

Where `script.py` is the application you are writing and currently having issues with. Notice that `icons` is a sibling of `script.py`.

Comment: relative path doesn't work,but absolute path do.